# Flask - connecting to multiple MySQL databases via my Flask application without using SQL-Alchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I'm creating a web application on the Flask RESTful framework to serve API requests to my mobile applications. Our requirement is to integrate with the databases of different clients dynamically to access data pertinent to transactions conducted via the mobile application which also requires access to our MySQL database.
I have used MySQL queries instead of SQL Alchemy on my Flask application to interact with the database. 
Is there a method to connect to multiple MySQL databases on Flask without using SQL Alchemy or having to create a new Flask server for each client?